# Photos Library: .photoslibrary file taking double of storage space in Photos app and Document Folder

Tags: photos, storage, macos

As you can see in the screenshot below the Photos app is using 53,1 GB of the total Disk Storage, but also the Documents Folder has a .photoslibrary file of 50,34 GB. I tried deleting the file from the Documents folder, but then I neither had the photoslibrary in Documents nor any photos in the Photos app. Also, there was round about 100GB more of available storage (both storages of 53,1GB and 50,34GB were gone). When I copied the photoslibrary file back in the Documents Folder, the 100GB were there again (Same Phenomen as before).

What can I do to avoid having two Files using double of the needed storage?

[image: Screenshot showing storage analysis]

Comment: It appears you are doulble counting the space.

Answer (score 2):

The reality is that there isn't two files taking up the double storage. The storage is only used once.

The view you're looking at is just confusing, since the "Fotos" and "Fotos-Mediathek" is really one and same.

You can open your home folder in finder and select the list view (command 2) and then calculate all folder sizes. Let finder add up all the space and you can verify you don’t have double space used.

Comment: Then: why is it not taking the same space for both? And why did I have 100GB more when I delete one of the files, which is only 50GB?

Comment: The "Fotos-Mediathek" only contains the photos within Photos.app, the "Fotos" label in your screenshot sums up both those as well as any photos you have that are not within Photos.app. In your screenshot you can see that you have some photo files within your Documents folder for example. The difference is small, because it is only few files compared to your Photos.app library.

Comment: How did you confirm that you have "100 GB more" - where did you read that and how? (I need this information in order to explain why it is so).